# How to map data to class structure using linq?

Tags: c#, linq, class, mapping

I have some raw data separated with comma like:

```
name value  Image              catID   ID

Blue, era , Colors/col_image       ,37  ,  1

pink, aka, Colors/col_image        ,37  ,  2
```

and I prepared a class structure like :

```
public class DailyStuffs
{
    public string StuffName { get; set; }
    public string ConvertedName { get; set; }
    public string StuffImage { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
}

 public class StuffType
{
   public string Category { get; set; }       
   public List<DailyStuffs> dailyStuffs;
}
```

I want to group item according to category(color,birds etc) . I tried using following code :

```
 List<StuffType> stuff = (from line in lines
                                      let data = line.Split(',').ToList()
                                      select new StuffType
                                      {
                                          Category = DefineRange(Convert.ToInt16(data[4])),
                                          dailyStuffs = (from dat in data select new DailyStuffs { StuffName = data[1] }).ToList()
                                      }).ToList();
```

and DefineRange is returning a string value :

```
private string DefineRange(int value)
   {
       if (value >= 1 && value <= 10)
       {
           return "Colors";
       }}
```

I am getting a wrong list with category as part of each item.

Any suggestion guys? How should I approach for this?

Comment: Can you please provide the mapping between your class properties (e.g. `DailyStuffs.CategoryId`) and the raw data (e.g. `catID`). It is a bit confusing because you seem to use `data[4]` for `StuffType.Category` although `data[4]` will give you the `ID` column from the raw data.

Comment: @YacoubMassad , I am passing data[4] into a function named : DefineRange() that helps to return Particular category name. Just now I got an idea to use group clause in linq query. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes I think you should the use grouping functionality from LINQ. But you did not answer my question. You are passing `data[4]`, shouldn't you pass `data[3]`? In general can you explain the relationship between you raw data columns and the properties in your model classes?

Comment: @YacoubMassad , yes i can also use data[3] , just another way of usage. Can u suggest something on group clause in this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have some errors in your code. The category column is `data[3]` and the name column is `data[0]`. The closest LINQ you can get to work with your design is:

```
var stuff = (from line in lines
             let data = line.Split(',').ToList()
             group data by data[3] into c
             select new StuffType {
                 Category = DefineRange(Convert.ToInt32(c.Key)),
                 dailyStuffs = (from s in c
                                select new DailyStuffs {
                                    StuffName = s[0],
                                    ConvertedName = s[1],
                                    StuffImage = s[2],
                                    CategoryId = Convert.ToInt32(s[3])
                                }).ToList()
             }).ToList();
```

Of course you have to fix your `DefineRange()` function to work with the `catID` column. Here is a [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7tm5ln). I entered more data for testing.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that I understand your mapping between raw data and class properties correctly, then you should do something like this:

```
var result = list.Select(str =>
        str
            .Split(',')
            .Select(v => v.Trim()).ToArray())
    .Select(x =>
        new
        {
            Name = x[0],
            Value = x[1],
            Image = x[2],
            CatId = Convert.ToInt32(x[3]),
            Id = Convert.ToInt32(x[4])
        })
    .GroupBy(x => x.CatId)
    .Select(x => new StuffType
    {
        Category = DefineRange(x.Key),
        dailyStuffs = x.Select(y => new DailyStuffs
        {
            CategoryId = x.Key, //Maybe instead here you want to put the Id?
            ConvertedName = y.Value, //I am mapping from Value to ConvertedName. Is this correct?
            StuffImage = y.Image,
            StuffName = y.Name
        }).ToList()
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks @Yacoub Massand